Storing ASCII code point value in a float prevents its interpretation as a character (in C)
float c;
c = 'a';
while (c <= 'z')
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
    c++;
}

write() is data type-agnostic.
It should deliver the correct code point values to the terminal.
The terminal should then interprete it according to its character encoding scheme (usually UTF-8).
Question
Why does this code output a blank line rather than the alphabet?
(the goal of this question is to understand the underlying mechanism at work)
What I have checked
I printed out the float values of each incremented c.
I seemingly always get the correct code point value ( 116.0000000 for 't', 117.0000000 for 'u' etc)
I suspect the problem arises from storing the code point values as floats, potentially causing precision loss somehow.

write() writes bytes without interpreting them.  It does not write values.  You told it to write the byte at the lowest address of the float variable.  That's what it did.

float and char have very different memory structure. Your expectation of what this code should do is incorrect.

The community is giving you good feedback on your code.  That said, I like people who think of different things and try them.  I had to do it in the beginning, and on sunny days I still do... Like I wondered if the Video address @ 0xA0000000 was available for use when my PC was not in "Graphics Mode."  Was it wrong to do this?  Yes.  Yes of course.  Did I learn a lot of things?  Yes, very much so!  Did I overwrite my CMOS a few times?  Yes, a lot.  :-(

You asked to write the first byte of the float. That does not produce anything useful.

Let's look at the following program instead:
char c = 'a';
write(1, &c, 1);

int i = 'a';
write(1, &i, 1);

float f = 'a';
write(1, &f, 1);

First of all, 'a' is an int, and it's equivalent to 97.[1]
c, i and f will be all be initialized to have the value ninety-seven, but that is represented differently by different types.

The char ninety-seven is represented by byte 61 (hex).[1]
The int ninety-seven is represented by bytes 61 00 00 00 or 61 00 00 00 00 00 00 00.[1]
The float ninety-seven is represented by bytes 00 00 C2 42.[1]

The subsequent calls to write output the first of these bytes.

61 for the char. Your terminal displays this as an a.[1]
61 for the int. Your terminal displays this as an a.[1]
00 for the float. Your terminal might display this as an empty space.



I'm assuming a modern desktop system.


int i = 'a'; write(1, &i, 1) prints out a on my terminal but float f = 'a'; write(1, &f, 1) prints indeed an empty space.
On my system, an int is 4 bytes.

The byte order of my system is based on little endian, which I guess explains why int i = 'a'; write(1, &i, 1); prints out a on my terminal.

@ikegami Homily: "The hurrier I go, the behinder I get!" Translated to the realm of coding, that becomes: "Every hour spent coding after midnight generates at least 2 hours of daylight debugging._" cf. "After Midnight" -- Clapton. "After midnight / We're gonna let it all hang out" ... and next morning, we're gonna try to tuck it all back in again... Cheerzzz-z-z-z-z-z-z-z
